# ranking into three categories Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, rank

I have a mean_v column and want to create a new column(rank_0-2) that would rank the mean_v into three categories. 0-2

How can i do it? I am using below code, which does the ranking but I need the rank value in three categories only (0-2)

```
df['rank_0-2'] = df.mean_v.rank(method='dense', ascending = False).astype(int)
```

| mean_v | rank_0-2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 |  |
| 0.00787 |  |
| 1.00787 |  |
| 0.222222222222222 |  |
| 0.277777777777777 |  |
| 0.363636363636363 |  |
| 0.00787 |  |
| 1.00787 |  |
| 0.222222222222222 |  |
| 0.4 |  |

Comment: How are we defining "rank" bottom third, middle third, top third (`df['rank_0-2'] = pd.cut(df['mean_v'], bins=3, labels=[2, 1, 0])`)? Or do you mean weighted? Some other criteria for categorising into classes 0, 1, and 2?

Comment: Yes, meant bottom third, middle third and top third

Comment: How would we do it if we want to do equally weighted? i.e the lowest 3rd of mean_v = 0 and highest 3rdof mean_v =2

Comment: `cut` should do that if you put the labels as `[0, 1, 2]` I just did it the other way because you had `ascending=False` in your shown code. For the shown example, the numbers are binned into the groups `[(-0.00101, 0.336], (0.336, 0.672], (0.672, 1.008]]`